# How do you send the contents of a fieldset to an email address?

Tags: html, forms, email

I have a fieldset:

```
        <div class="form-container container">
            <form id="contact-form" action="mailto:xyz@email.com" method="post">
                <fieldset form="#contact-form">
                    <legend>Contact Form</legend>
                    <label class="input-field-name">Name:<br />
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" name="Name"/>
                    </label><br />
                    <label class="input-field-name">Email:<br />
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" name="Email"/>
                    </label><br />
                    <label class="input-field-name">Message Title:<br />
                        <input class="input-field" type="text" name="Message Title"/>
                    </label><br />
                    <label class="input-field-name">Message:<br />
                        <textarea class="message-field" type="text" name="Message"></textarea>                            
                    </label><br />
                    <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I want to set it up so that the person who wants to contact me can enter their details and then when the 'Submit' button is clicked I receive an email with the Message Title as the header and the persons Name, Email and Message in the body of the email.

At the moment the mailto:xyz@email.com section will open up an email client successfully but I want it to just send automatically. I have some understanding of js and php but this is the first time I've tried something like this so was looking to be pointed in the right direction. I'm not asking for all the code, just what I need to do then I can work it out for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the moment the mailto:xyz@email.com section will open up an email client successfully but I want it to just send automatically.

You can't, at least not client-side.  The `mailto:` protocol handler is intended to simply launch the registered e-mail client for the user.  Nothing more.

> I have some understanding of js and php but this is the first time I've tried something like this so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction

You can send the e-mail server-side with PHP.  Don't bother with `mail()`, which is just a utility function for basic debugging and such.  Consider a robust e-mail class like PHPMailer.  That way, you can use secured SMTP servers, and also send HTML e-mails with proper multipart MIME encoding.

Comment: cheers for the pointers @Brad. Have found this great link for anyone looking to get into email handling with php and PHPMailer using SMTP https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/